# Hibernate StatelessSession and strange behavior on Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, orm

I am using Hibernate's StatelessSession for inserting and updating rows in bulk. Not sure if `jdbc.batch`_size is related to the question, but in any case in my application, I do not configure `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` parameter at all.

I supply to the session a connection object that is already thread-bound to an existing transaction (managed by Spring). This is done with Spring's `DataSourceUtils`. For this reason, I do not close the stateless session when I am done processing the data, because I still need the connection open for a few other things until the transaction is complete.

Basically, something like this:

```
statelessSession = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession(DataSourceUtils.getConnection(...));
// repeat many times
try {
    statelessSession.insert(entity);
}
catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
    statelessSession.update(entity);
}
// some more actions
// close transaction
```

On SQL Server, everything works as expected. Every `session.insert(...)` call runs the SQL and possibly fails on a unique constraint if I try to insert an existing row. When I eventually commit the transaction, everything works as I expect.

On Oracle, however, nothing happens. Hibernate logs print the SQL, but it simply doesn't run. Further more, the inserts don't fail when they should.

After debugging the Hibernate code, I found out that it is related to the JDBC batching behavior. I decided to explicitly flush the `statelessSession` using the `managedFlush()` method. Even then, I found out that I have to flush it after every command, otherwise it won't exhibit the fail-fast behavior that I want.

```
statelessSession = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession(DataSourceUtils.getConnection(...));
// repeat many times
try {
    statelessSession.insert(entity);
    ((Context) session).managedFlush()
}
catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
    statelessSession.update(entity);
    ((Context) session).managedFlush()
}
// some more actions not related to statelessSession
// close transaction
```

While this works, when I profiled my code I discovered that now it runs slower. Even on SQL Server where presumably the `managedFlush()` method has nothing to do.

Any idea what's going on? Is there any hidden configuration that I can tweak to achieve the desired behavior - something like "auto-flush" (but without auto-commit, of course)?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should close your session once you get an exception, because the Persistence Context might be left in an inconsistent state.

So you shouldn't update on any exception.

Quoting the [Session JavaDoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html):

> If the Session throws an exception, the transaction must be rolled
>   back and the session discarded. The internal state of the Session
>   might not be consistent with the database after the exception occurs.

In your example you can simply call merge because it works for both in
sert/updates:

```
statelessSession.merge(entity);
```

### Update

Since you are using MS SQL you might be using IDENTITY generator which [disables JDBC batching](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/). Latest MS SQL versions added support for Seqeuneces which are more friendly with batching anyway.

You need to enable [Hibernate batching support](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/sect-Performance_Tuning_Guide-Entity_Beans-Batching_Database_Operations.html), like:

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=30
```

If you don't set this property, the default value is 0, so there's no default JDBC batching.

Comment: The javadocs that you quote are on regular session, not stateless session. I am very familiar with them, but this is not the case here. Thanks,Yoni

Comment: Nope, no identity generator.

Answer (score 0):

Why works on SQL Server: 
SQL server supports READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level. This mean another transaction, can see uncommitted changes to a table.

Why not working on Oracle:
Oracle doesn't support READ UNCOMMITTED, it has only READ COMMITTED and SERIALIZABLE.
So another transaction, from "Oracle SQL Developer" or "Toad" can't see the still uncommitted changes of the transaction in your application.

Lets say "hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=20", and you want to make 100 inserts. Your application will send the inserts as 5 batches, each with 20 inserts. Another "READ UNCOMMITTED" transaction will see each individual batch. "READ COMMITTED" transaction will see nothing, until your application commits the transaction that produces the inserts.

Comment: This is not related. I have only one transaction in my use-case. Say I insert 5,000 records. I know some of them exist and will fail, but I expect the failure to occur immediately as I run the SQL insert command, so I can follow-up with an update.